# Table doesn't exist - returns 'Invalid Object Name'

Tags: sql, select, sqlfiddle

I'm using SQL Fiddle for a project. I built my schema in left panel, everything works out fine and I get the Schema Ready message. When I attempt to perform a Select query on the right table, it tells me the tables I just created do not exist. Here is the select statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1;
SELECT *
FROM table2;
```

Again, I am pretty sure the tables I created are working fine and are using an exact match to the names in my select statement. The error I receive says only, "Invalid object name 'table1'."

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you create your schema. The select statement doesn't tell us anything about why table1 wouldn't exist.

Comment: Also in SQLFiddle next to the Build Schema button there is a Browser button that will let you look at the table definitions that were created. Make sure that the table is showing up there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you are using the correct database, sometimes when you change from server to server you end up running the query on the master database of a server
2. If thats not the case, also put the name of the schema before the table as follows: schemaname.tablename

Comment: As said above, check if you are using the correct databse, to do so use "USE Database GO" to ensure its pointing to the correct database.

Comment: Can SQLFiddle even have more than one database or schema reference?